# How to use offset in arrays in bash?

Tags: arrays, bash, shell

Here is my code.

```
#! /bin/bash
array=(3 2 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0)
for i in {0..10}
do
    this=${array:$i:$((i+1))}
    echo $this
done
```

I want to print each number of my number separately. I have used this line to get the array elements using an offset number.

```
    this=${array:$i:$((i+1))}
```

However I am only getting 3 printed and rest all are new lines. I basically want to print 3, 2, 1 etc on separate lines. How do I correct this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you need to use the whole array `array[@]`, not `array`.

```
echo "${array[@]:3:2}"
```

Then, you may change the index to simple variable names:

```
this=${array[@]:i:i+1}
```

And then, you probably need to extract just one value of the list:

```
this=${array[@]:i:1}
```

Try this code:

```
array=(3 2 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0)
for i in {0..10}
do
    this=${array[@]:i:1}
    echo "$this"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to use an array slice here, just access the individual elements of the array. Try this:

```
#! /bin/bash
array=(3 2 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0)
for i in {0..10}
do
    this=${array[$((i+1))]}
    echo $this
done
```

In general you can access a single element of an array like that: `${array[3]}`.

Note that in this case, it would have been preferable to do this:

```
array=(3 2 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0)
for this in "${array[@]}"
do
    echo $this
done
```

Comment: What if the array was a string?

Comment: @lufork What do you mean? If the elements were strings? It shouldn't matter.

Comment: Like for instance say my array stored a line consisting "3 2 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0", then can I access 3rd element using array[3]?

Comment: @lufork If you have a string (say in a variable called `$str`) then you cannot use it as an array directly, but if you convert it to an array you can. For simple cases (such as `3 2 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0`) you can convert it like so: `array=($str)`.

Comment: The third element is `${array[3]}` and usually you want double quotes around variable interpolations.